# Error uploading to s3 bucket on android

Tags: android, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am trying to upload to S3 on android. However, it does not actually upload the image. The only thing resembling an error that I see is this:

D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: No valid credentials found in SharedPreferences

However, when googling it I find various conflicting information. The only real thing I can find is that this can be caused by not properly adding the cognito framework to the project, but I have verified that it is in the build.gradle.

I should also note that I have this working on iOS just fine using the same credentials. It was mentioned that I need to use a different identity pool per platform. So I created a new identity pool for Android and made sure I had matching permissions and it did not work either. Considering how iOS works fine and uploads the image without issue, I feel it has to be something with the code using on Android. I included that below.

There is this function to get credentials from cognito

```
    private CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider getCreadentials(Context context) {
    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    context.getApplicationContext(),
                    IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
                    Regions.US_EAST_1
            );

    return credentialsProvider;
}
```

And then the function to actually save the image to S3

```
    public void saveImage(Context context, Bitmap data, String key, Double lat, Double lon) {

    exifBuilder = new ExifBuilder(mContext, lat, lon);

    File file = writeImageToFile(context, data);
    s3 = new AmazonS3Client(getCreadentials(context));

    if (file != null) {

        TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, context.getApplicationContext());
        TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(
                BUCKET_NAME,
                key,
                file
        );
    }
}
```

I have verified that the file is not null. And also verified that it is the correct identity pool id.

Does anything here stand out as missing?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue cannot be derived from the above code. The "error" I was given was unrelated and just means that the cognito service has not previously established a user id for that device. The issue was however, the function being called above to save the image to S3 was called from a uithread, and since network activity cannot happen on a UI thread, it was not making the call. I figured this out after trying to output credentialsProvider.getProviderId() and received an error to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this issue and upload was not completing with either an error or success flag.

In my case it was because I was not declaring the `TransferService` in the manifest.

```
    <service
        android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService"
        android:enabled="true"/>
```

This prevents the upload from taking place, and the listener never gets notification.